# Spring Data Rest method 'PATCH' is not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

Do you know if method 'PATCH' is supported in `spring-data-rest` ? I have following repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

}
```

and when I'm trying to update one certain field of the user with following HTTP call:

```
PATCH http://localhost:8080/users/1  -d{'field1':'value1'}
```

I'm receiving error:

```
WARN 23413 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'PATCH' not supported
```

Do I need to add some additional configuration to make it work? 
I checked documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/) and assumed that it should work out of the box.

Comment: You're right, it should work for an item but not for a collection: Collections resources support both GET and POST. All other HTTP methods will cause a 405 Method Not Allowed.

Comment: but I specified item id in the URL so I suppose it should be mapped to particular entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad. I had another controller which overrides path for spring-data-rest one.